# Unity 3d 4.6 Raycast ignore alpha on sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG8Kd.jpg) I'm using a script on it to detect drag event so that the user can pull the scroll from the side of the screen. The problem is that I have a button that sits above the clay seal and it is being blocked by the Rect of the scroll picture. Since the scroll moves I cant exactly parent the button to it. So I'm asking if there is a way to ignore the alpha on the scroll and make ray casts pass trough it. I already have a script that uses a box collider and implements  the `ICanvasRaycastFilter` but it doesnt seem to work with the unity scroll rect for some reason. Here is the full script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RaycastFilter : MonoBehaviour, ICanvasRaycastFilter
{
    private RectTransform rectTransform;
    private new BoxCollider2D collider2D;

    public void Awake()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        collider2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    public bool IsRaycastLocationValid(Vector2 screenPosition, Camera raycastEventCamera) //uGUI callback
    {
        // If we don't have a collider we will simply use the big button box. //TODO: make custom exception for this.
        if (collider2D == null)
            return true;

        Vector2 localPoint;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rectTransform, screenPosition, raycastEventCamera, out localPoint);

        Vector2 pivot = rectTransform.pivot - new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        Vector2 pivotScaled = Vector2.Scale(rectTransform.rect.size, pivot);

        Vector2 realPoint = localPoint + pivotScaled;

        Rect colliderRect = new Rect(
            collider2D.center.x - collider2D.size.x / 2,
            collider2D.center.y - collider2D.size.y / 2,
            collider2D.size.x,
            collider2D.size.y); // TODO: CACHE

        bool containsRect = colliderRect.Contains(realPoint);

        return containsRect;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this like I did, here's my solution for raycasting sprites through alpha in a 3D world.

First, transform your hit point to the local space of the sprite using an inverse transform. Then, add the pivot point of your sprite. Since it is expressed in pixels, dividing it by the pixels per unit gives you the correct offset.
To get the UV values of that local point, divide it by the sprite bounds size. This will give you values between 0 and 1. Since our coordinate system is Y up and a texture is Y down, we'll have to invert our Y value.
Now it's easy to read the correct pixel. Multiply the UV with the texture width and height.

```
    private GameObject Raycast(Vector2 screenPos)
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(_camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos), _camera.transform.forward);

        var result = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, float.MaxValue).ToList().OrderByDescending(h => h.distance); //inverse raycast

        foreach (var hit in result)
        {
            var rend = hit.transform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
            if (rend == null)
                continue;

            Vector2 localPos = hit.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
            localPos += rend.sprite.pivot / rend.sprite.pixelsPerUnit;

            Vector2 uv = localPos / rend.sprite.bounds.size;
            uv.y = 1f - uv.y;

            Texture2D tex = rend.sprite.texture as Texture2D;

            int x = (int)(uv.x * tex.width);
            int y = (int)(uv.y * tex.height);
            var pix = tex.GetPixel(x, y);

            if (pix.a > 0)
            {
                return hit.transform.gameObject;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the ScrollRect Component? If not, you will really have a lot of problems, ScrollRect comes from the new UI and you don't have to code Input touches, it automatically provides a perfect Input Recognition for you.

You Can Add sliders to the ScrollRect as well. I suggest that you watch this video.

Add Slider Component to the ScrollRect aswell so you can customize a slider that "Doesn't Need for you to worry about RayCast Ignore"

Comment: I am using the ScrollRect, I don't need a slider since I'm using the DragOn and PointerUp events. The problems is that the Rectangle of the scroll is blocking the raycast to a button that is underneath it. Long story short I fixed it without fancy code by rearranging stuff in the scene so that they don't block  each other. Also your Answer isn't really a answer .